# Reference of frame in rolling motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose we have a rigid cylinder of mass ${M}$ and radius ${R}$ that is rolling down an inclined plane without slipping.

When describing the motion of the cylinder, when is it convenient to describe the motion from the point of contact with the surface and when is better to describe the motion from the center of mass of the cylinder?

I know it depends of what I'm asked to calculate but are there general advantages of each case?

For example, I know that when describing the motion from the point of contact with the surface, the relation ${a_t}$=${\gamma}$${w}$ is satisfied where ${a_t}$ is the tangential acceleration, ${\gamma}$ is the angular acceleration and ${w}$ the angular velocity

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference  an no advantage in one of the two description, only if you use energy conservation you have only rotation energy, from the point of contact, or you have translation energy of the mid + rotational energy around the axes.